# Evince fails to annotate text in right place

Tags: evince

I am reading a book with evince(version 3.30.1 on ubuntu 18.10) but find its notation function does not work properly

[image]

The source pdf file is in good quality because okular functions nicely.

[image]

I prefer the smooth design of evince than okular.

How could configure it to  get a good annotation tool?

Answer (score 1):

It [appears](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96764) this has to do with Poppler, which is not really a part of Evince, and thus has not been fixed yet.  It's caused on older pdfs by a mismatch in sizing between parts of the pdf format.  For a workaround, I just print the pdf to file, and replace the original file with the printed one, since that seems to fix the mismatch. You could also try other pdf readers.

Comment: Printing-to-file works!! This is such a life-saving trick, at least for now.  Thanks!

Comment: @YanKingYin it's work.